# Login error: call to undefined function entity_load in User module

Tags: users

I’m new to Drupal and I have a problem where no users can login (HTTP 500 and WSOD on POST of valid credentials, Drupal 7). The error message is:

“E_ERROR Error in file »user.module« at line 291: Call to undefined function entity_load()”

Any ideas on how to approach troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 0):

Your error's stating that it can't find a function that should be in drupal core. Check you includes folder. There should be a file in there called common.inc, make sure the function entity_load is defined in there.

Comment: Thanks Jance, includes/common.inc exists and contains entity_load(). Disabling the Devel module solved the issue. To the moderators: I want to publish the solution that helped me solve this problem for others who might encounter the same issue.